# How long will a TinyURL be available?

Tags: url, url-shortening

This is not a thread about if URL shortener are good or not, I'm just wondering how long such created [TinyURL](http://tinyurl.com/) will be available? Is the given URL available "forever"?

If so - is there a way to override such URL again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From their website:

> By entering in a URL in the text field below, we will create a tiny URL that will not break in email postings and **never expires**.

Obviously subject to the service existing indefinitely!

By override, do you mean modify the redirection target URL?  I can't readily see anywhere that this is stated, although I'm fairly sure it cannot be modified.

Comment: All links here, except for the one that was created only 23 hours ago, have expired: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/166/5

Comment: @user1271772 they work fine for me.

Comment: They are all working for me too now. Must have been a glitch yesterday, when only the most recent one worked, and the rest of them took me to TinyURL where it said "Page not found"